# How can I change the size of a gameobject with a float var?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I had idea in unity to make a square that as I gain points, it increases in size. Is there any way I can have the size change to a float variable?

Answer (score 1):

you can using vector3 by using a localscale transform.
The variable in Vector3 is float type.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Example() {
        // Widen the object by 0.1
        transform.localScale += new Vector3(0.1F, 0, 0);
    }
}
```